# I want to stop at each index of an array and wait for event listeners before moving on

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach, addeventlistener

I want to reuse an existing loop function I have for a different array, but to have it stop between indexes and wait for an event listener.

The problem is this function only stops once it loops through the full array. I also want to keep the "character by character" typing effect. I've tried to play with the function, but I can't figure it out.

Here is the existing typing effect/looping function I want to also use to loop through a different array called `questions[]` and have it type through each string and pause between each index, waiting for the user to hit a button and then get a response. I'll be using `buttonOne.addEventListener` to then type out a response, and to also trigger the next question from `questions[]`.

```js
const element =
  document.querySelector("div");

const messages =
  ["Hello, my operating name is Zurlan-42", "more stuff", "more things"];

const typingText = (elem, txt, done = () => {}) => {
  let i = 0;

  elem.textContent = ""; // Clear before typing

  const next = () => {
    elem.textContent += txt[i];

    if(i === txt.length - 1)  return done();

    i += 1;
    setTimeout(next, 30);
  };
  next(); // Start
};

const typingArray = (elem, arr, done = () => {}) => {
  let i = 0;

  const next = () => {
    typingText(elem, arr[i], () => {

      if(i === arr.length - 1) return done();

      i += 1;
      setTimeout(next, 2000);
    });    
  };
  next(); // Start
}
typingArray(element, messages, () => {
  console.log("All Done!");

  setTimeout(() => {
    element.textContent = "";
  }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Here is what I have so far. I keep bouncing back and forth between using forEach method or just writing out each function for each question and response. But, I feel like looping through an array(s) is the better way to go.

```
const questionOne = () => {
    buttonOne.textContent = "No Arms";
    buttonTwo.textContent = "No Legs";

    buttonOne.addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log("I was clicked!");
        
    })
    buttonTwo.addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log("No, I was clicked!");
    })
}
questionOne();
```

Comment: Do not use the `typingArray` function but with each click from the _"conversation"_ pass the next text-snippet/sentence from the `messages` array to `typingText` (by e.g. [`shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)ing the string from it).

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I'll reference more of Mmdn web docs. There are so many things you can do with arrays, completely forgot about shift, sort, pop, etc.

Answer (score 1):

A way to achieve the goal of waiting for the user input to show the next *message* could be changing your `typingArray` function so that, instead of waiting for some time to pass before going to the next one, it will create dynamically the buttons containing those answers (user input) having as click event handler the logic to process the next question.

Here I name that function as `processQuestions` having `index` as argument so that when the answer buttons will be created by `createAnswerButtons` their click event handler will have a call with an index pointing at the next question each time.

I also added a very basic strategy to determine if the answer given was correct and also a style that will better please the eye.

```js
const questions = [
  { q: 'Question1.. ?', a: ['Answer1', 'Answer2'], correct: 0 },
  { q: 'Question2.. ?', a: ['Answer1', 'Answer2', 'Answer3'], correct: 1 },
  { q: 'Question3.. ?', a: ['Answer1', 'Answer2', 'Answer3'], correct: 2 }
];

const questionElem = document.querySelector('.question');
const answersElem = document.querySelector('.answers');

//this is your original function to type text delaying each character
const typingText = (elem, txt, done = () => {}) => {
  let i = 0;
  elem.textContent = "";
  const next = () => {
    elem.textContent += txt[i];
    if (i === txt.length - 1) return done();
    i += 1;
    setTimeout(next, 30);
  };
  next();
};

//creates the buttons in the .answers area according to the passed answers
const createAnswerButtons = (answers, correct, callback) => {  
  answers.forEach( (answer, i) => {
    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.textContent = answer;
    button.onclick = callback;
    //if the index of the current answer is the same as the correct one
    if(i==correct)
      //add the class correct to the answer button
      button.classList.add('correct');
    answersElem.appendChild(button);
  });
};

const processQuestions = (questions, index = 0) => {
  
  //if there are no more questions
  if (index >= questions.length) {
    console.log("All questions completed");
    return;
  }

  //get the current question according to the index
  const currentQuestion = questions[index];

  //instructs your typingText func to start typing the current question  
  typingText(questionElem, currentQuestion.q, () => {
    //and when the typing has been finished,
    //create and show the correspondent answer buttons
    createAnswerButtons(
      currentQuestion.a,
      currentQuestion.correct,
      //this is the callback that will be bound to the buttons click event
      //and when one of the answer button was clicked,
      (event) => {              
        //report result
        const isAnswerGivenCorrect =
          event.target.classList.contains('correct');
        printResult(index, isAnswerGivenCorrect);
        
        //then clear the area and pass to the next question
        questionElem.textContent = '';
        answersElem.innerHTML = '';
        processQuestions(questions, index + 1);
      });
  });
};

function printResult(index, wasCorrect){
  const output = document.getElementById('output');
  if(wasCorrect)
    output.textContent = `q${index+1} The answer given was correct!`;
  else
    output.textContent = `q${index+1} The answer given was wrong!`;
}

processQuestions(questions);
```

```css
#output{
  margin-top: 1em;
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

#output:empty{
  display: none;
}

.container {
  border: dashed 2px lightgray;
  padding: 1em;
}

.container .question {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.container .answers {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.container .answers button{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="question"></div>
  <div class="answers"></div>
</div>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the detailed reply and notes. First off, I didn't know you could have an array broken up into sections like that. I like how clean and simple that is: combining two array possibilities into one. For the ```button.onclick = callback;``` I see that callback is a parameter that is passed to the button. Then the function ```createAnswerButtons``` is passed into ```processQuestions```. You access the ```currentQuestion.a``` from the questions parameter you passed, but how does the callback come into play? A little confused on the fundamentals of that.

Comment: it might be easier to read if you stop thinking in terms of lexical scope and imagine how and when those functions will be actually executed. `processQuestion` is the entry point. It will begin a chain that will keep calling itself each time with an index incremented and that will finally return only when such index exceeded the questions length. At each step of execution it will refresh the questions area creating one button for each answer belonging to it. Such operation is performed by `createAnswerButtons`..

Comment: that will assign to each button the callback passed, as their click event handler. Such callback is defined upper in the call stack when `index` is known and passed as incremented by 1. So the key is that when the button will be clicked, the function bound to the event will be aware of the index that will call again `processQuestions(questions, index + 1)`. So imagine that sequence: processQuestion(1) -> showQuestionAndAnswers(1) -> [user click button] -> processQuestion(2) -> showQuestionAndAnswers(2) -> [user click button] ...

Comment: Definitely looked up lexical scope, ha. I see your point and that clears it up for me. This was very helpful, thanks again.